# War - Card Game - With Betting - Java

Tags: java, try-catch

My problem is with the try and catch in my Deal; method. Not sure why the error is popping up under next. In the console box youll see how it runs, it stops after dealing a few cards to players, when it should deal all the cards and ask to play again. What am i overseeing ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
public class finalproject {



private static final String reader = null; 
private static int X = 0;
private static int Y = 0;
private static String Names = "";
private static File outfile = new File("/Users/josephbosco/" + Names +".txt");
private static int AmountOfPlayers = 0;
private static int AmountOfDecks = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean numberError = true;

int Y = 0; 
    do {



      Deal();  //This is line 30
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println( " Would you like to play again? Press 1 or press any    other key ");
  Y = input.nextInt();

  try { 
    System.out.print(" Would you like to play again? Press 1 or press any other key ");
    String TheNames = Scanner.next;  //Read into a string
    Y = Integer.parseInt(TheNames.trim());
    numberError = false;  //if we haven't bailed out, then the number must be valid.

} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("The value you provied is invalid...Please try again");     //error message is for user
    numberError = true;  //Uh-oh...We have a problem.
    }

} while (Y == 1) ;


}





public static void Print() {    
    Scanner myScanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = "/Users/JosephBosco/" + ".txt";
    String TimeStamp = CurrentTimeStamp("");
    printToFile ( fileName, TimeStamp +"\r\n");

     }




    public static void printToFile ( String myFileName, String message) {
        try {            

            File outfile = new File("/Users/josephbosco/" + Names +".txt");

             if (!outfile.exists()); {
                outfile.createNewFile();
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outfile.getAbsoluteFile(), true);  
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                                    System.out.println( " New Player, begins with  $100 ");
                bw.write ( Names + " $100 ");
                bw.flush();  
                bw.close();                     

                }    
             }

    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(" Uh oh! Something happened!!");
        e.printStackTrace(); }

        }
    public static void Deal() {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                 boolean numberError = false;


        do {
        try { 

            System.out.println(" Welcome players to War with betting! How many players are there?");
            String enteredString = myScanner.next(); 
            AmountOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(enteredString.trim()); 
            numberError = false;
            }
        catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println( " That number is invalid! Please try again " + e); 
         numberError = true;
         String garbage = myScanner.next(); 
            }
        } while (numberError == true);

        System.out.println( " \n Thankyou, that was a valid Number ");
        System.out.println( AmountOfPlayers + " Players will play War!");

        String[] ListOfNames = new String[AmountOfPlayers];

         for( int Y = 0; Y <  ListOfNames.length; Y++) { 
                System.out.print(" Enter the player's name: " + ( Y+1 ) + ":");
                Names = ListOfNames [Y] = myScanner.next();
           Print();
               }
         do {
               try { 

                System.out.println(" Okay, so, how many decks would you like to play with? " ); 
                   String enteredString = myScanner.next(); 
                   AmountOfDecks = Integer.parseInt(enteredString.trim()); 
                   numberError = false;
                   }
               catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println( " That is an invalid Number! Try again " + e); 
                numberError = true;
                String garbage = myScanner.next(); 
                  }
               } while (numberError == true);
               System.out.println( " \n That was a valid Number ");
               System.out.println( AmountOfDecks + " is the amount of decks to be used!");
               System.out.println( " Press enter to start game ");
               new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();



  String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
 String[] numbers = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"};

         int[] Deck = new int[52 * AmountOfDecks]; {

                for( int i = 0; i < Deck.length; i++) Deck[i] = i;

                for( int i = 0; i < Deck.length; i++) {

                    int index = (int)(Math.random() * Deck.length);
                    int temp = Deck[i];
                    Deck[i] = Deck[index];
                    Deck[index] = temp;
                            }




                    for( int Q = 0; Q < AmountOfDecks; Q++) {  //Line 157 has         nothing on it??? its the line above the first "for"
                    for( int Y = 0; Y < Names.length(); Y++); {
                    for( int V = 0; V < Deck.length; V++ ) {    
                        String suit = suits[Deck[V] % 4];
                        String number = numbers[Deck[V] % 13];
                    System.out.print( ListOfNames[Y] + " drew " + " : " + number + suit + "\r\n");
                    Y++;
            }

                    }
                    }
               }
   }




    public static final String CurrentTimeStamp ( final String TimeStamp) {
        String CurrentTimeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(new Timestamp( new java.util.Date().getTime()).toString()).format(new java.util.Date());
       return CurrentTimeStamp;
          }
   }
```

**CONSOLE BOX**

```
 Welcome players to War with betting! How many players are there?
3

 Thankyou, that was a valid Number 
3 Players will play War!
 Enter the player's name: 1:Joe
 New Player, begins with  $100 
 Enter the player's name: 2:Mike
 New Player, begins with  $100 
 Enter the player's name: 3:Tom
 New Player, begins with  $100 
 Okay, so, how many decks would you like to play with? 
2

 That was a valid Number 
2 is the amount of decks to be used!
 Press enter to start game 

Joe drew  : 4Hearts
Mike drew  : 4Spades
Tom drew  : 4Spades
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at finalproject.Deal(finalproject.java:157)
     at finalproject.main(finalproject.java:30)
```

Comment: "Okay so here is my code, I'm not sure whats wrong with it." is more or less a guarantee nobody will look at your stuff. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you should post the method where that error is... cause in this current state we cant see which line is 101 and 28

Comment: this line makes no sense at all : `private static final String reader = null; `

Comment: I fixed a bunch of stuff, i edited and posted the new code, my only error is with the try and catch in the "deal" method at the top. Am I overseeing something? I dont get any suggestions when I click on the error.

Comment: Do not vandalize your post; you have committed its content to this site, and it stays.

Comment: (If you really want to get rid of it, flag this post for moderator attention and ask nicely)

Comment: So, you think you are entitled to help, and to ignoring the rules of the site you ask at? Speak about snobbery...

Comment: How am I ignoring the rules of the site? No one was helping me, andI know other kids in my class go on this site so I didn't want them to see my unfinished code and try to submit it as their work. wtf is everyones deal, if you're on this site it should be to help others and find answers. IF i had answers I'd give them out, and help everyone, unfortunately I dont, and I'm not very good at this and need a lot of help. Not afraid to admit it, but every time I do ask for help, one of you, not all, but someone has to be a dick for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line that doesn't make sense to me and shouldn't complie is this.

```
Names = Names [Y] = myScanner.next();
```

You are setting the `String[] Names` to a single String value.

Comment: I actually figured it out, I had to change names to ListofNames, and i Got it to work. Thanks tho

Comment: K, cool. your code is still quite messy, but I'll let you deal with that. ;)

Comment: Yeah I'm new to it, this is the final assignment of my intro class, it's pretty intense haha

Comment: I fixed a bunch of stuff, i edited and posted the new code, my only error is with the try and catch in the "deal" method at the top. Am I overseeing something? I dont get any suggestions when I click on the error.

Comment: Never change the code from your original question as it invalidates the answers. Always make a new question for new issues.

Comment: sorry dude, it wouldnt let me ask another queation, said I had to wait a week. And my projects due tonight! :/

Comment: Well your current error is an OutOfBoundsException. The error gives you the line number and maybe the index that you are trying to access. Even if the line is blank, look for where you access a list, then think about the problem. How big is the list? Are you accessing it at a negative position or a position that is greater than or equal to the size of the list? That is the source of the error.